# List selection as Set<String> - how to use?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

Am playing around with SwiftUI and am obviously not getting it.

Basic example which works and is just displaying the selected name.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let names = ["Joe", "Jim", "Paul"]

    @State var selectedName = Set<String>()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(names, id: \.self, selection: $selectedName) { name in
                Text(name)
            }
            if !selectedName.isEmpty {
                Text(selectedName.first!) // <-- this line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is a textfield where that name can be changed. Tried many ways but getting another error every time.

```
TextField("Name", text: $selectedName)
```

> Gives this error: Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Set<String>>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'

```
TextField("Name", text: $selectedName.first!)
```

> Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Binding<((String) throws -> Bool) throws -> String?>'

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may make a binding by yourself:

```
 TextField("Name", text: Binding<String>(get: {self.selectedName.first!}, set: { _ in}) )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I look all the solutions everywhere and yours is the best!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can't pass `Binding<Set<String>>` to `Binding<String>`. Here gives you an idea or solution to change selectedName variable using TextField:

I added a new variable which is `Binding<String>`. Then I change the selectedName inside the TextField's `onCommit` closure.

```
struct ContentView: View {

let names = ["Joe", "Jim", "Paul"]

@State var selectedName = Set<String>()
@State var textFieldName = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List(names, id: \.self, selection: $selectedName) { name in
            Text(name)
        }
        if !selectedName.isEmpty {
            Text(selectedName.first!)
        }

        Text(textFieldName)

        TextField("Name", text: $textFieldName, onEditingChanged: { (Bool) in
            //onEditing
        }) {
            //onCommit
            self.selectedName.insert(self.textFieldName)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my alternate if I'd needed to edit some value of `names` having in one screen and list and edit field and make them all synchronised and not confuse each other.

Here is full testable module (tested on Xcode 11.2/iOS 13.2). As I tested it for iOS there are API requirement for put `List` into EditMode to process selection, so this included.

```
struct TestChangeSelectedItem: View {
    @State var names = ["Joe", "Jim", "Paul"] // made modifiable
    @State var selectedName: String? = nil // only one can be edited, so single selection

    @State var editMode: EditMode = .active // Tested for iOS, so it is needed

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(selection: $selectedName) {
                ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode) // Tested for iOS, so it is needed

            if selectedName != nil {
                Divider()
                Text(selectedName!) // Left to see updates for selection
                editor(for: selectedName!) // Separated to make more clear
            }
        }
    }

    private func editor(for selection: String) -> some View {
        let index = names.firstIndex(of: selection)!
        var editedValue = selection // local to avoid cycling in refresh

        return HStack {
            Text("New name:")
            TextField("Name", text: Binding<String>(get: { editedValue }, set: { editedValue = $0}), onCommit: {
                self.names[index] = editedValue
                self.selectedName = editedValue
            })
        }
    }
}

struct TestChangeSelectedItem_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestChangeSelectedItem()
    }
}
```